# Unable to pass data between a table view and another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, segue

I'm having trouble transferring data between a table view controller and another view controller. 
On my sending controller - tableviewcontroller.m - I have this under `prepareForSegue:`

```
FriendDetailViewController *fvc = (FriendDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
PFUser *u = self.friends[path.row];
fvc.nameLabel.text = u.username;


//friendViewController.m (the destination view controller)
- (void)viewWillLoad { 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (self.user) {
        self.nameLabel.text = self.user.username;
    }else{
        self.nameLabel.text = @"No data to display";
    }
}
```

The label displays "No data to display".

I've read other posts and viewed tutorials but I cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only setting the nameLabel in your `prepareForSegue`, not the actual user, so it is uninstantiated when your new VC loads.

Try adding this into your `prepareForSegue`:

```
fvc.user = u;
```

Assuming your user you want to pass is stored in u, that should do it (also assuming user is a public property of the new view controller.)

Comment: Thank you so very much Bill! This worked. So what this does is pass the selected user to the destination view controller?

Comment: Correct. So what you were doing was only setting the name label's text, with the line `self.nameLabel.text = u.username`. All you could really access about the user was the username, by accessing the value of the nameLabel's text, but you never actually gave the entire user object over to the new VC, so to that new one it doesn't exist yet. Hopefully that explanation made sense!

Comment: Yes, it does make sense and helps to clarify why I couldn't get the user object in the next VC. Would the same implementation work for the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Yes it would, and if you're doing everything in code, very often `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will be where you set up your next view controller.

Comment: Hey Bill, I added the same code to the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but again the object is not being sent to the `friendDetailViewController`. I logged it and get a `(null)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the UI actions on `prepareForSegue`.

You could instead define the `user` variable on destination `viewcontroller`.

After that, on `prepareForSegue`, you can set the selected PFUser to the destination `viewcontroller's` `user`.

And when you'd like to show the user's name, use `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewWillLoad`.

If you can't understand, please let me know, I can show detailed code for all.

Comment: I can see where you're going with this but as @MoLow stated, adding code will certainly clarify your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an attribute in your .h file of FriendDetailViewController and the set it before calling:

```
fvc.attribute = u.username;
```

After this, you can call pushViewController for "fvc" inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: In my .h file of FriendDetailViewController i have `self.nameLabel.text = self.user.userName;` 
I don't need to use the pushViewController since I have the segue hooked up to the prototype cell. I added pushViewController and it sent me to a blank dark screen. I pretty much have the same code in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath as prepareForSegue but I'm getting the same issue trying to send the object to the next VC. @GabrielaNogueira